# Reading lines from text file and store in character array in C++

Tags: c++

I got stuck in reading lines from file and store them in dynamic character array. Here is the code. Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
Input file:  >sequence1.txt 
             WAWAWAWA
```

The program should ignore the line starting with `>`. It does but gives output `WWWWWWWW`.

```
while(!rrr.eof())
{     
    rrr.get(ch);
    int j;
    if(ch == '>')
    {
        cout<<ch<< "  ignored "<<endl;
        getline(rrr,line);
    }
    else
    {
        getline(rrr,line);
        j= line.length()+1;
        arr= new char[j];
        for(int i=1; i<=j;i++)
        {
           rrr.get(ch);
           arr[i]=ch;
           cout<<arr[i];
        }
        len=j;
    }

    rrr.get(ch);    
}
```

Comment: don't use `eof()` as a loop condition. eof state is only set by an input operation. there is no such before the loop.

Comment: note that `getline` gets a *line*.

Comment: also you would do well to check whether each attempted input operation succeeds.

Comment: yup u r rite. what condition should i use that  reads all lines of file which in this case is two but can vary. Ignore line starting with >. And store second line in a dynamic character array.

Comment: i tried   for(string line;getline(rrr,line);) as loop condition. it works well but problem is with reading character by character

Comment: Watch out for memory leaks. Can you use another string?

Comment: Another string for??

Comment: If we could all simultaneously agree to stop using `char*` and `char []`, that would be peachy.

Comment: What is the for loop doing getting characters from the file, _after_ you called `getline` to read the whole line?

Comment: see the edit on the answer ...

Answer (score 0):

To make the code looks simpler, I would change this:

```
rrr.get(ch);
int j;
if(ch == '>')
{
    cout<<ch<< "  ignored "<<endl;
    getline(rrr,line);
}
else
{
    getline(rrr,line);
    j= line.length()+1;
    arr= new char[j];
    for(int i=1; i<=j;i++)
    {
       rrr.get(ch);
       arr[i]=ch;
       cout<<arr[i];
    }
    len=j;
}

rrr.get(ch);
```

To this:

```
getline(rrr, line);

if(line[0] == '>')
{
    cout<<line[0]<< "  ignored "<<endl;
}
else
{
    len = line.length();
    arr= new char[len];
    for(int i=0; i < len; i++)
    {
       arr[i] = line[i];
       cout << arr[i];
    }
}
```

Even though I'm not sure why would you need the for loop. while you can just assign or copy the line value to arr!

What is the usage this arr is unclear.

Comment: Thanx Mehrdad. Actually I am almost new to this and don't know much abt. It worked! But it reads first line correctly but ignores 1st letter of second line....any words on that

Comment: I just need to store line not starting with '>' in a character array to process further

Comment: I have updated my code. and this time tested it. it works as I understand your problem.
Here you can check the code and try it: http://cpp.sh/5vi6
Use the Text Standard Input as your input file.

Comment: Ok bro i am working on global pairwise allocation. Can u help me if i send u the entire code to trace errors??

Answer (score 0):

I guesse you want this ...

```
vector<string> data;
string line;
while( getline(rrr,line))
{     
    if(line[0] == '>')
        cout << "> ignored " << endl;

    else
     data.push_back(line);

}
```

then print data...

//////////////////////////////////////////

With dynamic array...

```
    string line;
    int count = 0; // count lines without '>'
    while( getline(rrr,line))
        if(line[0] != '>')
             ++count;


 // return to beg of file
    rrr.clear();
    rrr.seekg(0, ios::beg);


    char** data;
    data = new char*[count];
    int i = 0;
    while( getline(rrr,line))
    {     
        if(line[0] == '>')
            cout << "> ignored " << endl;

        else {
         data[i] = new char[line.length() + 1];
         for(int _i = 0; _i < line.length() + 1; ++_i)
              data[i][_i] = line[_i];
          ++i; // next row
     }

    }
```

Comment: Vector is simple but i am directed to use dynamic array

Comment: It same idea! just replace vector to array and storage! you use 1d array, must use 2d array if you want storage all liines!

Comment: Thnx all finally i got it solved. Thanx Mehrdad in particular u got my problem rite!! God bless u all.